# What are the differences between Skyroot Aerospace's Vikram-S and Vikram-1?

Tags: launch-vehicle, sub-orbital, qualification-testing

Skyroot Aerospace (an Indian aerospace startup ) is ready to launch its first launch vehicle Vikram-S, which is the suborbital version of Vikram-1.

What are the differences in flight hardware between Vikram-S and Vikram-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [news article](https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/indias-first-private-rocket-to-be-launched-between-november-12-16/article66111011.ece) (emphasis mine)

> The Vikram-S rocket is a **single-stage sub-orbital** launch vehicle which would carry ...

Key takeaways are **single stage** and **sub orbital**.

From this [tweet](https://twitter.com/SkyrootA/status/1592386764207194112?s=20&t=68HqvdPpDGqqUKj3t9TF4w) it appears that it has spin stabilization (in or after some stage). This [tweet](https://twitter.com/SkyrootA/status/1591664839860326401?s=20&t=68HqvdPpDGqqUKj3t9TF4w) indicates that it has a single solid stage.

From this [article](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/national/indias-first-privately-built-rocket-set-for-november-15-launch/article66127482.ece) (emphasis mine)

> ... has successfully **built and tested** ... **cryogenic, hypergolic-liquid, and solid fuel**-based rocket engines...

The future orbital rocket is likely to have cryogenic / liquid stages also.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikram_(rocket)) (emphasis mine)

> The Vikram I, first rocket in the series, has **three solid fuel-powered stages** ... and **the final stage is Raman engine**. The Raman engine is powered by MMH and NTO liquid fuels ...